# How is it possible to have a short interest greater than 100%?

Tags: stocks, shorting-securities

Currently when you look at NYSE: GME (GameStop Corp.), according to [MarketWatch](https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/gme) the company has a short interest of 136.56% since 09/15/20.

How exactly is this possible? Is this just a faulty data point, or does the calculation take into account other derivatives like unexercised put options?

[image]